# How to prioritize the top group by keyword in vba

Tags: excel, vba

The current execution results have the functions of grouping and topping, but I hope to be able to sort the results indirectly according to the order of column v

I hope that the results of the execution will be sorted like pictures. Please help me how to make adjustments to make the functions complete.
[Compare the two pictures, hoping to sort the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okvOQ.jpg)

Comment: So you want the results to follow the order of (in this case) 111 then 109 and then (or if there's no 111/109) from low to high or the way they went into the Data_dic?

Comment: If there is no data in column V or there is irrelevant information in column C, it will be arranged according to the size of the number of TEAM in column C. Currently, this part is included, but according to my current VBA, it cannot be sorted like the question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on this for a bit and got it to work with a recursive function (it was my first time trying it out so it's likely not "optimal") and ofc working with arrays for speed.

The sorting works with or without the BIG-sort values. If there's a team with the same name, that's sorting properly as well (smallest team first) even if they have BIG-values. Teams with multiple BIG-values get the first-big value sorted above and if different teams have the same BIG-value then the smallest team comes first (like with the rest).

```
Option Explicit
Dim hasImportance_dic As Object
Dim funcIteration As Long

Sub RETEAM()
    Dim Data_dic As Object
    Set Data_dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set hasImportance_dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim lRow As Long, arr, lRowV As Long, arrSort, amtSorted As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("team0")
    lRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lRowV = ws.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & lRow).value
    If lRowV > 1 Then arrSort = ws.Range("V2:V" & lRowV).value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'counting the teams
        If Not Data_dic.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
            Data_dic.Add arr(i, 3), 1
        Else
            Data_dic(arr(i, 3)) = Data_dic(arr(i, 3)) + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    'giving the team with importances a dictionary key so all can be sorted to the top later
    If Not IsEmpty(arrSort) Then
        Dim aSortRank As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            aSortRank = aSortNeed(arrSort, arr(i, 2))
            If aSortRank > 0 Then
                If Not hasImportance_dic.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
                    hasImportance_dic.Add arr(i, 3), aSortRank
                Else
                    hasImportance_dic(arr(i, 3)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(aSortRank, hasImportance_dic(arr(i, 3)))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    Dim arrSorted(), dict As Object
    ReDim arrSorted(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 4)
    arrSorted(1, 1) = Data_dic(arr(1, 3))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2) 'filling in the first spot of the sorted array
        arrSorted(1, i + 1) = arr(1, i)
    Next i
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1) 'sorting the whole list and placing in front what grouping they belong to
        arrSorted = sortArr(arrSorted, arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arrSort, Data_dic(arr(i, 3)), i)
    Next i
    Data_dic.RemoveAll
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSorted, 1) 'checking what the size of each group will be
        If Not Data_dic.Exists(arrSorted(i, 1)) Then
            Data_dic.Add arrSorted(i, 1), 1
        Else
            Data_dic(arrSorted(i, 1)) = Data_dic(arrSorted(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim arrPrint
    Dim j As Long, currGr As Long, k As Long, p As Long
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To Data_dic.Count 'basically used for offset as well
        currGr = arrSorted(j, 1)
        ReDim arrPrint(1 To Data_dic(arrSorted(j, 1)), 1 To 3) 'print array needs to get the correct size
        p = 1
        Do While currGr = arrSorted(j, 1) 'filling the print array
            For k = 1 To 3
                arrPrint(p, k) = arrSorted(j, k + 1)
            Next k
            j = j + 1
            p = p + 1
            If j > UBound(arrSorted, 1) Then 'exiting while without throwing an error with the array boundries
                j = 1
                currGr = -1
            End If
        Loop
        ws.Range("A2").Offset(0, i * 3).Resize(UBound(arrPrint, 1), UBound(arrPrint, 2)).value = arrPrint 'printing per 3 columns
    Next i
    
    Set Data_dic = Nothing
    Set hasImportance_dic = Nothing
End Sub


Function sortArr(a, gr, name, team, aSort, amt, amtSorted) As Variant()
    Dim j As Long, Sorted As Boolean, recursiveNeeded As Boolean
    Dim temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4
    funcIteration = funcIteration + 1
    Debug.Print "Going into the function " & funcIteration
    If Not IsEmpty(aSort) Then
        j = 1
        Do While (j < amtSorted) And (Not recursiveNeeded)
            If amt < a(j, 1) Then 'grouping needs to come before the one we're comparing with
                recursiveNeeded = True
            Else
                If amt = a(j, 1) Then
                    If team = a(j, 4) Then
                        If aSortNeed(aSort, name) > 0 Then
                            If aSortNeed(aSort, a(j, 3)) > 0 Then
                                If aSortNeed(aSort, a(j, 3)) > aSortNeed(aSort, name) Then 'in case multiple sort-values are in the same team
                                    recursiveNeeded = True
                                End If
                            Else
                                recursiveNeeded = True
                            End If
                        Else
                            If (name < a(j, 3)) And (Not aSortNeed(aSort, a(j, 3)) > 0) Then
                                recursiveNeeded = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                        If hasImportance_dic.Exists(a(j, 4)) Then
                            If hasImportance_dic.Exists(team) Then
                                If hasImportance_dic(a(j, 4)) > hasImportance_dic(team) Then
                                    recursiveNeeded = True
                                ElseIf hasImportance_dic(a(j, 4)) = hasImportance_dic(team) And team < a(j, 4) Then
                                    recursiveNeeded = True
                                End If
                            End If
                        ElseIf hasImportance_dic.Exists(team) Then
                            recursiveNeeded = True
                        Else
                            If team < a(j, 4) Then
                                recursiveNeeded = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If recursiveNeeded Then
                temp1 = a(j, 1)
                temp2 = a(j, 2)
                temp3 = a(j, 3)
                temp4 = a(j, 4)
                a(j, 1) = amt
                a(j, 2) = gr
                a(j, 3) = name
                a(j, 4) = team
                a = sortArr(a, temp2, temp3, temp4, aSort, temp1, amtSorted)
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Else
        j = 1
        Do While j < amtSorted And Not recursiveNeeded
            If amt < a(j, 1) Then
                recursiveNeeded = True
            ElseIf amt = a(j, 1) Then
                If team = a(j, 4) Then
                    If name < a(j, 3) Then recursiveNeeded = True
                Else
                    If team < a(j, 4) Then recursiveNeeded = True
                End If
            End If
            If recursiveNeeded Then
                temp1 = a(j, 1)
                temp2 = a(j, 2)
                temp3 = a(j, 3)
                temp4 = a(j, 4)
                a(j, 1) = amt
                a(j, 2) = gr
                a(j, 3) = name
                a(j, 4) = team
                a = sortArr(a, temp2, temp3, temp4, aSort, temp1, amtSorted)
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    End If
    If Not recursiveNeeded Then
        a(j, 1) = amt
        a(j, 2) = gr
        a(j, 3) = name
        a(j, 4) = team
    End If
    sortArr = a
End Function

Function aSortNeed(aSort, val) As Long
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 1 To UBound(aSort, 1)
        If aSort(k, 1) = val Then
            aSortNeed = k
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next k
    aSortNeed = 0
End Function
```

Hope it is clear enough and if not, feel free to ask questions. I'm quite happy with the result (not with how it's written but getting it/recursive function to work as intended, will probably throw this in a codereview post to see what can be done better at some point)

**Edit:**

To make the groupings that have no values and have the empty teams appear in the first grouping (no repeating teams), adjusted only the main sub:

```
Sub RETEAM_FIXED()
    Dim Data_dic As Object
    Set Data_dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set hasImportance_dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim lRow As Long, arr, lRowV As Long, arrSort, amtSorted As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("team0")
    lRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ws.Range("D2:U" & lRow).ClearContents
    lRowV = ws.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & lRow).value
    If lRowV > 1 Then arrSort = ws.Range("V2:V" & lRowV).value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'counting the teams
        If Not Data_dic.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
            Data_dic.Add arr(i, 3), 1
        ElseIf Len(arr(i, 3)) > 0 Then
            Data_dic(arr(i, 3)) = Data_dic(arr(i, 3)) + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    'giving the team with importances a dictionary key so all can be sorted to the top later
    If Not IsEmpty(arrSort) Then
        Dim aSortRank As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            aSortRank = aSortNeed(arrSort, arr(i, 2))
            If aSortRank > 0 Then
                If Not hasImportance_dic.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
                    hasImportance_dic.Add arr(i, 3), aSortRank
                Else
                    hasImportance_dic(arr(i, 3)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(aSortRank, hasImportance_dic(arr(i, 3)))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    Dim arrSorted(), dict As Object
    ReDim arrSorted(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 4)
    arrSorted(1, 1) = Data_dic(arr(1, 3))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2) 'filling in the first spot of the sorted array
        arrSorted(1, i + 1) = arr(1, i)
    Next i
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1) 'sorting the whole list and placing in front what grouping they belong to
        arrSorted = sortArr(arrSorted, arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arrSort, Data_dic(arr(i, 3)), i)
    Next i
    Data_dic.RemoveAll
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSorted, 1) 'checking what the size of each group will be
        If Not Data_dic.Exists(arrSorted(i, 1)) Then
            Data_dic.Add arrSorted(i, 1), 1
        Else
            Data_dic(arrSorted(i, 1)) = Data_dic(arrSorted(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim arrPrint
    Dim j As Long, currGr As Long, k As Long, p As Long
    Dim lastGrouping
    lastGrouping = arrSorted(UBound(arrSorted, 1), 1)
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To lastGrouping 'basically used for offset as well
        currGr = arrSorted(j, 1)
        If currGr <> i Then GoTo skipEmptyColumns
        ReDim arrPrint(1 To Data_dic(arrSorted(j, 1)), 1 To 3) 'print array needs to get the correct size
        p = 1
        Do While currGr = arrSorted(j, 1) 'filling the print array
            For k = 1 To 3
                arrPrint(p, k) = arrSorted(j, k + 1)
            Next k
            j = j + 1
            p = p + 1
            If j > UBound(arrSorted, 1) Then 'exiting while without throwing an error with the array boundries
                j = 1
                currGr = -1
            End If
        Loop
        ws.Range("A2").Offset(0, i * 3).Resize(UBound(arrPrint, 1), UBound(arrPrint, 2)).value = arrPrint 'printing per 3 columns
skipEmptyColumns:
    Next i
    
    Set Data_dic = Nothing
    Set hasImportance_dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that I renamed the sub so there can't be any name-issues now.
Here's an example to showcase that it does work as intended:
[image: fixed example]

Comment: CALL "Function aSortNeed(aSort, val) As Long" ，but "For k = 1 To UBound(aSort, 1)" Type Mismatch

Comment: Are you using my full code? Unless aSort is not filled with something, that shouldn't happen and with my code you shouldn't get there with this `If Not IsEmpty(arrSort) Then` check. (I don't have any `Call` in my code.

Comment: call means execute，The error stops at For k = 1 To UBound(aSort, 1), and it shows a type mismatch，i really don't know what the problem is

Comment: `Call` is deprecated and since I didn't have it in my code, I'm wondering what else you changed that would cause this to happen? The type mismatch is probably because no array was passed as an argument. Note that all of my code combined is to replace all of your old code.

Comment: I looked at the syntax. If there is no non-repeated team string in column D to F, it seems that it will be used by other repeated team strings. I hope that it will be like a stacking folder, column D-F (column C has only one single string without repetition), column G-column I (column C has 2 repeated strings), column J-column L (column C has 3 repeated strings), column M-O (column C has 4 repeated strings), column P-R (column C has 5 repeated strings), column S-U Column (column C has repeated 6 strings)

Comment: I use your grammar completely, and don't use other added instructions, so I wonder where the problem is, is the last paragraph really VBA programming?

Comment: Then where did the `Call` come from? Or did you just mean when it is getting executed? And yes, it is VBA programming and tested by me (several times).

Comment: I know where I went wrong. I copied a copy and grafted it in my program model, and a copy is in your complete new model. Because the subroutine is the same, there is a conflict error. I am really sorry that I misunderstood your program.

Comment: It is runnable. To execute the program, you need to click the RETEAM macro again to run it. Is there a way to click execute to run it directly?

Comment: In addition, the result is as I thought, that is, no team of this type collapses to the left, and my original program has a blank space. I hope Notus_Panda can help to adjust it.

Comment: What do you mean, no team collapses to the left? Where is/What "blank space"? You can insert a button to activate the code if that's what you mean. Also, you can rename the sub I gave you, that shouldn't be an issue :)

Comment: I use pictures to understand the meaning better, but my text explanation is really poor

https://upload.cc/i1/2023/07/26/QEFs2C.jpg

Comment: In addition, an unreasonable judgment was tested. If the C column of the cell is blank, and there are strings in the A and B columns, the more blanks in the C column will be divided into new other groups

Comment: So you want the columns empty if there are none in x-amount, i.e. D/E/F empty if there are no 1-amount, etc. ? Or you don't want this to happen because my version doesn't keep empty columns already..

Comment: .https://upload.cc/i1/2023/07/26/DlriU9.jpg
I hope that the blank column can be kept as shown in the figure, and the data without strings in column C can be in column D-F

Comment: See my edit for the modifications.

Comment: The operation is perfect, the test of multiple sets of data is correct, and the execution speed is very fast

Comment: Ah, just what we wanted, glad it worked out!

Comment: Thank you,
Notus_Panda God, let me learn excellent grammar, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Range("G1:I9").Sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

The sorting of the data in the V column is not necessarily exactly as I mentioned. If the first value of V is 110 and the second is 108, the sorting will be incorrect.

[as the picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMoDc.png)